# Waiting for ImageView.animate() to end before proceeding with the rest of the code

Tags: java, android, multithreading, animation

I'm a beginner learning android development and I was trying to make an image switch using fade in and out animation using ImageView.animate().alpha(); what I found is that the image changed before the animation finished so no animation was seen.

my code is

> ```
>    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageToChange);
>    image.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000);
>    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
> ```

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For waiting for the animation end you might use [this example from the Android site](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html#animate) and `setListener` method.

If you want the view to become visible you need to set `alpha(1f)`. Also, try `setImageResource` before animation (switch line 3 with 2).

Comment: Apparently the code got cut off short, it was going to fade out then fade back in,, thanks for the reply